# Disable autovacuum for one (pretty much read-only) database in a cluster

Tags: postgresql, autovacuum

I’ve got a PostgreSQL cluster on my development system in which I’ve created several databases. I also have a dump of the last state of the DB of an old system imported in which I (very) occasionally need to look something up, so this database is pretty much read-only, while the others are live (if low traffic except for the Akonadi one).

I am finding lots of instructions for disabling `autovacuum` either globally (i.e. for the entire DB cluster) or for individual tables, but how can I permanently disable it for just one database in the cluster?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by disabling `autovacuum` on that one database?

Comment: @mustaccio I had an autovacuum process whose argv in `ps ax` output showed that database hanging in D state on the system when it overloaded, so I think it somehow ran.

Answer (score 0):

In a database that is "pretty much" read-only, the `autovacuum` daemon will  "pretty much" (to the same degree) not actually schedule any `VACUUM` or `ANALYZE` commands because those are only triggered after a certain amount of write operations. Consult the [GUC settings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-autovacuum.html) `autovacuum_vacuum_insert_threshold`, `autovacuum_analyze_threshold` etc. for details.

**So you don't have to do anything.**

Notable [exception:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-autovacuum.html#GUC-AUTOVACUUM)

> Note that even when this parameter is disabled, the system will launch
> `autovacuum` processes if necessary to prevent transaction ID
> wraparound. See [**Section 24.1.5**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-WRAPAROUND) for more information.

To keep the autovacuum daemon from even running cheap but futile checks on your read-only tables, you can otherwise disable autovacuum ***per table***:

```
ALTER TABLE public.tbl SET (autovacuum_enabled = off);
```

For all user tables:

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE (
      SELECT string_agg(format('ALTER TABLE %I.%I SET (autovacuum_enabled = off)', schemaname, tablename), '; ')
      FROM   pg_tables
      WHERE  schemaname NOT LIKE 'pg\_%'
      AND    schemaname <> 'information_schema'
      );
END
$do$;
```

Enable normal autovacuum activity again with:

```
ALTER TABLE public.tbl RESET (autovacuum_enabled);
```

Technically, you can also:

```
ALTER TABLE public.tbl SET (autovacuum_enabled = on);
```

But, I quote [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#RELOPTION-AUTOVACUUM-ENABLED):

> Note that the `autovacuum` daemon does not run at all (except to
> prevent transaction ID wraparound) if the [`autovacuum`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-autovacuum.html#GUC-AUTOVACUUM) parameter
> is false; setting individual tables' storage parameters does not
> override that. Therefore there is seldom much point in explicitly
> setting this storage parameter to `true`, only to `false`.

Related blog post:

- https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/enabling-and-disabling-autovacuum-in-postgresql/